# Parallel Stacks debug window in Visual Studio 2017 not displaying output for successive async/await calls

Tags: c#, visual-studio, task-parallel-library, visual-studio-debugging

I'm trying to confirm if the following observed behavior in the **Parallel Stacks** debugger window is normal (Visual Studio 2017 15.8.5).

If either of the blocks, **Parallel Stack-1** or **Parallel Stack-2**, are ran in isolation during separate runs, then the Parallel Stacks output seems OK. However, if they are ran together in sequence, during the same debug session, then there is no output for the **Parallel Stack-2** statements.

Below are screen shots of the stack traces at each of the breakpoints.

```
namespace TaskYield
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task TaskYield()
        {
            await Task.Yield();
        } /*BREAKPOINT-2*/

        static async Task TaskDelay()
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Parallel Stack-1
            var ty = TaskYield();
            ty.Wait(); /*BREAKPOINT-1*/

            // Parallel Stack-2    
            var td = TaskDelay();
            td.Wait();
        } /*BREAKPOINT-3*/
    }
}
```

**Parallel Stack-1**

BREAKPOINT-1

[image: BREAKPOINT-1]

BREAKPOINT-2

[image: BREAKPOINT-2]

**Parallel Stack-2**

BREAKPOINT-3

[image]

Comment: Are you asking why sometimes there is only Program.Main at breakpoint 3? That's timing related. The screenshot shows Main after the wait and another thread right after the point of releasing the wait in the main thread. 1ms later that other thread would disappear.

Comment: @usr *"Are you asking why sometimes there is only Program.Main at breakpoint 3?"* - I am not asking that... I've stepped through every line, with various timings of steps between runs to try and coax some output.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the "bad" situation? I am not yet clear on what the question is.

Comment: @usr The erroneous situation happens when stepping through both sets of statements, *Parallel Stack-1* and *Parallel Stack-2* - no output for the *Parallel Stack-2* statements is shown in the *Parallel Stacks* window. If the *Parallel Stack-2* statements are ran by themselves (by commenting out *Parallel Stack-1*), then output shows OK.